# Google Map not loading in emulator

Tags: android

I am new to android and  working on GPS application. I use google map in this application but it show blank mapview  .

Firstly, I have find MD5 and SHA1 fingerprint.
then using SHA1 I got google APi key.
I used that key in my app.

I have set all the permissions but still the map is not loading ..
and at logcat window it shows error..

**failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**
and **could not get connection factory client**.

Please guide me..Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1 . create emulator with api 15 or below 18 
2 . start emulator
3 . downlaod com.android.vending-20130924.apk and com.google.android.gms-20130924.apk file     from net
4 . open command promt
5 . switch path to E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130911\sdk\platform-tools in command promt,
6 . install downloaded apk file explicitlly to emulator with command,
    adb install com.android.vending-20130924.apk.apk 
    and adb install com.google.android.gms-20130924.apk 
7. run application

above steps will  load google map in emulator